# To what extent does Time Dilation occur?

Tags: spacetime, time, time-dilation

[Time Dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation) is a fundamental concept in the theory of relativity, encompassing both special and general relativity. It describes the phenomenon where time appears to pass differently for observers in relative motion or under the influence of strong gravitational fields. However, the observable effects of time dilation can vary depending on specific conditions and factors. I would like to know about the extent to which time dilation can be observed and measured in practical situations, and what methods are used to detect its presence.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Experimental testing of time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_testing_of_time_dilation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Satellites of the [GPS network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) need to take into account time dilation, to correctly predict the time that passed, and the position of objects on the surface.

Comment: There is not a general rule of when it should be taken in consideration. You calculate the time dilation and compare it to the interval of your event to see if it makes sense to consider such phenomenon

Comment: Thanks for answering @LolloBoldo but what I mean is that time dilation requires another reference for us to even say that it has taken place. But to what extent is it possible so that it is even considered. Wouldn't that also make time obsolete?

Comment: You become much more aware of time dilation once you understand that it is the cause of gravity. Every time you drop your fork on your table, you realize that the only reason it fell is because time runs a little slower at the table than it does a few inches above. Your consciousness of time dilation increases dramatically when you start to think of it as something that affects your life every single minute.

Comment: Thank you @foolishmuse. I think I get it now. Gravity should be set as a standard for measuring the difference which also lets you know of you state.

Comment: Yes @ShubhankarDixit , time dilation always require 2 separete frames to be evaluated. The time dilation between the 2 frames is what you evaluate. As you correctly stated, time alone is not a well defined concept in GR

Comment: You have made a very interesting point.  As others have said, we have always thought that time dilation requires two frames to be measured.  But based on your idea, I wonder if we can measure time dilation in a single frame, simply with gravitational acceleration. For example we could say that on Earth, time dilation is 9.8m/s^2.

Comment: No @foolishmuse, you always need 2 frames by definition. Given an event, time dilation is defined as the ratio $\tau_1 / \tau_2$ where the two $\tau$ are the durations of such event in the two reference frames. If you remove one of them then it has no meaning

Comment: @LolloBoldo yes you are right. When you look at it my thought would still require the frame of deep space with no time dilation against which the measurement is done

Comment: Yes, in this sense you can consider time dilation on the surface of Earth against deep space, flat by definition in GR